# Rigorous Proof of $0!=1$

Tags: number-theory, combinatorial-proofs

From a philosophical standpoint, $0!=1$ as it is possible to arrange nothing in one way--there isn't.

Are there any rigorous proofs showing this concept?

Comment: There are lots of ways to see that $0!=1$ makes sense, but ultimately, the factorial is a tool that humans made up because it is useful, so we are free to define $0!$ in whatever way is most useful. The fact that $0!=1$ is so useful in so many ways and in so many contexts is the kind of thing that makes math so cool to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factorial function is defined to count the number of bijections between finite element sets, namely $n!=$ # $  f: \{1,..,n\} \to \{1,..,n\}$ that are bijective. 
There is precisely one bijective map $f : \emptyset \to \emptyset$, namely f is the empty map.

I recognize this is a very odd concept. Hope this helps.

Comment: The factorial **can** be defined in such a way; there are similar, but non equivalent definitions of $n\mapsto n!$ which are valid.